# node.js - how do I know all (recursive) "http.request" end?

Tags: node.js

Everything is async. Http.request is getting a function callback when it's done.
The problem is the function that calls http.request is being called recursively and non deterministically based on the results of the http request.

How do I know when I'm REALLY done in this async world?
simply keep as "tasks started vs. tasks completed" counters? 
Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: You should use promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module has many helpful utilities for organizing your asynchronous tasks.

For example if you had an array of urls you wanted to GET:

```
var http = require('http');
var async = require('async');

var urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://nodejs.org', 'http://stackoverflow.com'];

async.map(urls, function(url, cb) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    var buf = '';
    res.on('data', function(d) {
      buf += d;
    }).on('end', function() {
      cb(null, buf);
    });
  });
}, function(err, responses) {
  // responses is an array containing response bodies of a GET to each url:
  // responses[0] = response for google.com
  // responses[1] = response for nodejs.org
  // ...
});
```

Comment: How does this map to my situation? I have no idea how man GETs i'll need. The more "GET"s I make, the more "GETS" I may need, recursively, non-deterministically, depending on what the content of the body means.

Comment: Then use something different, such as [`async.queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue). `async` is very flexible...

Answer (score 0):

It is a good question, and currently there is a better solution:

Create a promise and use promise.all, if you want 100% async, use the promise resolve to call the function again with the next arg.

This way it is possible to be 100% sure that once the last promise was fulfilled all the others were fulfilled.

I do recommend async.queue to have a controlled level of concurrency processing